# Flutter web build issue

Tags: flutter, github, github-pages

i build a web app using flutter. the run seems to work perfectly fine. haven't used firebase.
the build version shows a white screen no matter what i do. i'm trying to upload this to my github for hosting.  can't seem to understand what i'm doing wrong. please help.

[currently for mobile/tablet devices, i have this page only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuLPM.jpg)
[index.html of the build release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdSJt.jpg)
[pubspec for plugins that are used in the projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP178.jpg)
[build release view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j4eD.jpg)
[console for the index.html opened from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LcKi.jpg)

things i've tried:

- removing  tag
- changing  to '/github_path/' , '/github_url/' , './' , '' , '/'
  tried most of all the possible solutions regarding this issues from reddit, stackoverflow and github forums. can't get this working on the build as well. only works on run.